# Why is the Orange dot setting parent with the object?

Tags: mesh, objects, vertices

Orange dot is setting parent with the object (the tree) I want to set parent the tree with low poly leaves, so I tried to delete this dot but it's not deleting,

I think it's a mesh plane scaled on 0 and I merged it by distance and then I built a tree with one vertex from beginning. Now the tree and that dot are linked on each other and I cant separate them nor with  <kbd>P</kbd>. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: If you're talking about the orange dot in the middle of the house with the dotted lines pointing to it, that is the origin of the tree trunk and the lines show that the leaves are parented to it. I suspect you added the object that makes up the trunk when the 3D cursor was at the world origin and then moved the trunk in Edit mode which would leave the origin where it was. To reset the origin to the trunk, select just the trunk and then go to the Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry menu.

Comment: thanks a lot, I figured out how to fix it but anyways thank you very much for a helpful responding <3